# SQL - Dateadd on working hours only?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I wonder if anyone could help?

I have a table that has the following columns

```
creationdate (datetime)
SLAhours (int)
```

I want to create a column called `completebydate` which would be a `dateadd` function adding on the SLA hours to the creation date. However I only want it to count 9am to 5pm on the creation date table.

For example, if an `SLAhour` value is 9, and the create datetime is '01 sep 2017 12:30' then the `completebydate` would be '02 sep 2017 13:30" instead of '01 sep 2017 21:30'

Does this make sense? Is this easily doable?

Comment: wouldn't it be 1430? so for the creationdate, you basically want it to always be 0900 when performing the dateadd function? What happens if the SLAhours is 15? How would you handle the roll over?

Comment: How do you know the working hours? Weekends and national holidays make this a bit complex.

Comment: I'd go the [UDF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/create-user-defined-functions-database-engine) route... but it could become very complex very quickly if you need to also keep track of holidays etc. (as mentioned before). In which case I'd just calculate the end-date in the application itself and store the calculated date in SQL.

Comment: If the SLAhours is 15 it would have to go forward 2 days. The working hours are always 9-5 - weekends and national holidays aren't to be taken into account.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is doable. You can create a trigger on this new column completebydate and write you logic in the trigger. so the trigger will populate the date automatically if the other columns are inserted.

If you have large volume of records incoming trigger is not recommended option.

Answer (score 0):

There are many different ways of implementing this, anywhere from writing it out in a [view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/views), to a [udf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/create-user-defined-functions-database-engine), to a [trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql). You might need to provide more context around the situation for someone to advise on which one is best for you.

Regardless of how you do it, the logic could look like this:

```
declare @example table
    (
        creationdate datetime
        , slahours int
    )

insert into @example
values ('2017-09-01 12:30', 9)
    , ('2017-09-01 16:00', 12)

declare @hrs_in_day int = 8
    , @end_time time = '17:00'

select b.creationdate
, b.slahours
, dateadd(hh, b.hr_cnt, dateadd(d, b.day_cnt, b.creationdate)) as completebydate
from (
    select a.creationdate
    , a.slahours
    , a.day_cnt + case when a.hr_cnt > a.first_day_remaining_hours then 1 else 0 end as day_cnt
    , a.hr_cnt + case when a.hr_cnt > a.first_day_remaining_hours then -1 * @hrs_in_day else 0 end as hr_cnt
    from (
        select e.creationdate
        , e.slahours
        , datediff(mi, cast(e.creationdate as time), @end_time) / 60.0 as first_day_remaining_hours
        , floor(e.slahours / @hrs_in_day) as day_cnt
        , e.slahours - (floor(e.slahours / @hrs_in_day) * @hrs_in_day) as hr_cnt
        from @example as e
        ) as a
    ) as b
```

The first sub-query is not necessary, just makes the code easier to understand.

**Output:**

```
creationdate             slahours   completebydate
2017-09-01 12:30:00.000     9       2017-09-02 13:30:00.000
2017-09-01 16:00:00.000     12      2017-09-03 12:00:00.000
```

As far as the weekend/holiday issue, that might warrant a separate question, but I would also take a look at [existing questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47275645/backward-scheduling-to-exclude-holidays/47277184#47277184) around the same concept.